# Synergy cannot reset on Mac

Tags: osx-yosemite

A really simple but dragged me many days that I cannot figure out how:
I've setup synergy on my Mac as a client, using Ubuntu as the server.
But now I wanted to switch to use Mac as server and Ubuntu as client.
The question now I'm facing is that synergy settings page never show up, each time I try to open it, it just appears in less than 0.1 second, then it disappeared.
Because I've set it up already and I don't need the reconfigure the Ip addresses etc.
This is convenient.
But now I wanted to switch server/client roles, I need to reconfigure it, however the settings page of synergy never shows up to let me configure it, does anyone have the same issue?
I tried to uninstall synergy on my Mac, but when I reinstall it back, it automatically configures itself again and quickly disappears and runs in the background.

It's been a pain for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't start the Server on Yosemite, because you need to grant access to the process (Synergy) to control your computer:

http://mizage.com/help/accessibility.html

doing that with Synergy should work.